# DataContext passthrough with ContentProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I would like to create a custom control that simplifies the following code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Label>First Name</Label>
        <TextBox Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"></TextBox>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Label>Last Name</Label>
        <TextBox Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"></TextBox>
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

My thoughts was to make a `UserControl` like the following, (Layout is a little bit different, but thats out of scope):

```
<UserControl x:Class="LabelControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Text}" Margin="2" MinWidth="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"></Label>
        <Grid Margin="2">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Control}" ></ContentControl>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The code behind exposes 2 Dependency properties:

- Text: the content of the label
- Control: the control to be hosted by the content. 
  The class uses the `ContentProperty` attribute to map the children to the `ContentControl`.

Thus allowing me to simplify my `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <controls:LabelControl Text="First Name">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"></TextBox>
    </controls:LabelControl>
    <controls:LabelControl Text="Last Name">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"></TextBox>
    </controls:LabelControl>
</StackPanel>
```

The problem I am running in to is the bindings in the the control are not mapping. Is there any way around this? The Label Controls DataContext is overridding the parent controls context.

Here is the code behind for the LabelControl:

```
[ContentProperty("Control")]
public partial class LabelControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text", typeof(string), typeof(LabelControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Control", typeof(Control), typeof(LabelControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(Control)));

    public Control Control
    {
        get { return (Control)GetValue(ControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControlProperty, value); }
    }

    public LabelControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Edit: Output confirms the datacontext is overriding.

```
BindingExpression path error: 'FirstName' property not found on 'object' ''LabelControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=FirstName; DataItem='LabelControl' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Comment: You should see any binding errors in output window.

Comment: @MikkoViitala I added a example binding error.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your binding like this if your `LabelControl` is contained within `Window` and it's `DataContext` has the `FirstName` property.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
</TextBox>
```

---

If you don't want to specify `RelativeSource` every time, you could use your  `LabelControl` as you do now...

```
<StackPanel>
    <controls:LabelControl Text="First Name">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"></TextBox>
    </controls:LabelControl>
    <controls:LabelControl Text="Last Name">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"></TextBox>
    </controls:LabelControl>
</StackPanel>
```

...and change the `LabelControl`'s implementation instead.

First, loose the `DataContext` assignment from the `LabelControl`'s codebehind.

```
public LabelControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //this.DataContext = this; // we don't want this
}
```

Then change the XAML template as

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Text,
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
           Margin="2" MinWidth="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
    </Label>
    <Grid Margin="2">
        <ContentControl 
            Content="{Binding Path=Control, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Now you should have your `DataContext` set up right.

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid having to use `RelativeSource` every time?

Comment: I was able to test this successfully:
 `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.FirstName,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"></TextBox>`

This really is not an ideal solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using `UserControl` was not the most ideal solution. It turns out that a templated control allows for the DataBinds to pass through without any hackery (RelativeSource).

```
[ContentProperty("Control")]
public class LabelControl : Control
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", 
        typeof(string), typeof(LabelControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Control", typeof(Control), typeof(LabelControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(Control)));

    public Control Control
    {
        get { return (Control)GetValue(ControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

In app.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:LabelControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:LabelControl">
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Text}"  MinWidth="100" FontSize="11"></Label>
                    <Grid Margin="2">
                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Control}"></ContentControl>
                    </Grid>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: @MikkoViitala Yes this did. Alot cleaner.